# Why can’t I delete files when using the “remote-ftp” for Atom

Tags: ftp, sftp, atom-editor

I can create a file, but not delete it with the `remote-ftp` (version 2.2.4 by icetee) for Atom.

This is not a permissions issue, as I have tested it with full `user:group` ownership rights over a file and its parent directory.

Additional proof of the issue not being permissions related is that I can use a third-party software — like FileZilla — and it will be able to delete the file (same sFTP credentials).

This issue happens to  me across multiple VPS servers - so I figure I am consistently configuring the `.ftpconfig` file incorrectly, or it’s a bug in the `remote-ftp` module? No one else has seemed to reports it, so back to it probably being all my fault? Here is my config file:

```
{  
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "host": "IP_ADDRESS",  
    "port": 22,  
    "user": "USERNAME",  
    "pass": "SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE",  
    "promptForPass": false,  
    "remote": "/",  
    "local": "",  
    "agent": "",  
    "privatekey": "",  
    "passphrase": "",  
    "hosthash": "",  
    "ignorehost": true,  
    "connTimeout": 10000,  
    "keepalive": 10000,  
    "keyboardInteractive": false,  
    "keyboardInteractiveForPass": false,  
    "remoteCommand": "",  
    "remoteShell": "",  
    "watch": [],  
    "watchTimeout": 500,  
    "filePermissions":"0644" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue is Atom related, and not related to the remote-ftp package. The fix [was discussed here](https://github.com/icetee/remote-ftp/issues/1347#issuecomment-726282213) on this issue report for the package on GitHub.

This is what the report says:

> “So there is an issue with Atom dialogs which causes it not to call the callbacks that would enable the actual delete. This won't be patched until 1.54, for now, I edited the remote-ftp command.js file with the following code on line 279 and restarted Atom. This causes the delete to happen without prompting, so be careful. Once 1.54 rolls out, just undo the code.”
>
> Before
>
> ```
> 'remote-ftp:delete-selected': {
>       enabled: true,
>       command() {
>         if (!hasProject()) return;
>
>         const remotes = getRemotes('You need to select a folder first');
>         if (remotes === false) return;
>
>         atom.confirm({
>           message: 'Are you sure you want to delete the selected item ?',
>           detailedMessage: `You are deleting:${remotes.map(view => `\n  ${view.item.remote}`)}`,
>           buttons: {
>             'Move to Trash': () => {
>               remotes.forEach((view) => {
>                 if (!view) return;
>
>                 const dir = Path.dirname(view.item.remote).replace(/\\/g, '/');
>                 const parent = remoteftp.treeView.resolve(dir);
>
>                 client.delete(view.item.remote, (err) => {
>                   if (!err && parent) {
>                     parent.open();
>                   }
>                 });
>               });
>             },
>             Cancel: null,
>           },
>         });
>       },
> ```
>
> After
>
> ```
> 'remote-ftp:delete-selected': {
>       enabled: true,
>       command() {
>         if (!hasProject()) return;
>
>         
>
> const remotes = getRemotes('You need to select a folder first');
>         if (remotes === false) return;
>
>         remotes.forEach((view) => {
>           if (!view) return;
>
>           const dir = Path.dirname(view.item.remote).replace(/\\/g, '/');
>           const parent = remoteftp.treeView.resolve(dir);
>
>           client.delete(view.item.remote, (err) => {
>             if (!err && parent) {
>               parent.open();
>             }
>           });
>         });
>
>         // atom.confirm({
>         //   message: 'Are you sure you want to delete the selected item ?',
>         //   detailedMessage: `You are deleting:${remotes.map(view => `\n  ${view.item.remote}`)}`,
>         //   buttons: {
>         //     'Move to Trash': () => {
>         //       remotes.forEach((view) => {
>         //         if (!view) return;
>         // 
>         //         const dir = Path.dirname(view.item.remote).replace(/\\/g, '/');
>         //         const parent = remoteftp.treeView.resolve(dir);
>         // 
>         //         client.delete(view.item.remote, (err) => {
>         //           if (!err && parent) {
>         //             parent.open();
>         //           }
>         //         });
>         //       });
>         //     },
>         //     Cancel: null,
>         //   },
>         // });
>       },
>     },
> ```

I was able to implement this temporary fix and it worked.

If anyone else uses it be careful because deletions are instant (no confirm/prompt popup box asking you to verify your action), and as another user recommended you’ll want to remember to undo this edit when Atom 1.54.0 (or higher) comes out.

Comment: This is a decent solution, but instead of commenting out the `atom.confirm` method you could also rename it to `atom.confirm_OFF` so `atom.confirm({` will become `atom.confirm_OFF({`. By renaming the method, it is effectively “removed” from the core logic; thus achieving the same goal as removing the method outright.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting the whole block, didnt work, since it doesn't call the delete method. But was usefull to point where the problem is. So use this one instead; note that one line of code added.:

```
'remote-ftp:delete-selected': {
  enabled: true,
  command() {
    if (!hasProject()) return;

    const remotes = getRemotes('You need to select a folder first');
    if (remotes === false) return;

    // atom.confirm({
    //   message: 'Are you sure you want to delete the selected item ?',
    //   detailedMessage: `You are deleting:${remotes.map(view => `\n  ${view.item.remote}`)}`,
    //   buttons: {
    //     'Move to Trash': () => {
          remotes.map(view => `\n  ${view.item.remote}`);   // remove after bug is fixed
          remotes.forEach((view) => {
            if (!view) return;

            const dir = Path.dirname(view.item.remote).replace(/\\/g, '/');
            const parent = remoteftp.treeView.resolve(dir);

            client.delete(view.item.remote, (err) => {
              if (!err && parent) {
                parent.open();
              }
            });
          });
    //     },
    //     Cancel: null,
    //   },
    // });
  },
},
```